# match clause returning incorrect results

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts3

I am trying to use FTS3 in sqlite and executing a query which is not returning desired results. here is the query:

```
select * from table1 where col1 MATCH 'rain';
```

this query is returning col1 containing text 'strain' too which I do not want. I want the exact replica of this query:

```
select * from table1 where col1 like '% rain %';
```

any suggestions/comments/help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of FTS3/FTS4 in sqlite database, I conclude that the default tokenizer which is simple (at least) ignores '(' and ')' while tokenizing the elements in any text column. Other special characters can also be checked as I doubt there would be others too. When the match query is executed, these values were ignored. Here is the test case for my scenario:

```
create virtual table tab1 using fts3(val text);
insert into tab1 values('this is rain test');
insert into tab1 values('this is strain test');
insert into tab1 values('this is (rain) test with parenthesis');
insert into tab1 values('rain test');
insert into tab1 values('this is rain');
insert into tab1 values('strain test');
insert into tab1 values('this is strain');
```

after executing the following query:

```
select * from tab1 where val MATCH 'rain';
```

results were:

```
this is rain test
this is (rain) test with parenthesis
rain test
this is rain
```

Comment: Thank you Ludo for your help and support.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why you get this result. You should only get results with matching terms for the MATCH query you posted. Can you post your FTS3 `CREATE TABLE` statement?

For example:

```
SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mail USING fts3(subject, body);
sqlite> INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) VALUES(1, 'software feedback', 'found it too slow');
sqlite> INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) VALUES(2, 'software feedback', 'no feedback');
sqlite> INSERT INTO mail(docid, subject, body) VALUES(3, 'slow lunch order',  'was a software problem');
sqlite> select * from mail where body match 'back';
sqlite> select * from mail where body match 'feedback';
software feedback|no feedback
```

Comment: count query is returning different values when i run both the queries on the original data. When i used your queries on your tables, it worked correctly. Its really strange. here is what I am doing:

create virtual table table1_fts4 using fts4(id number, val text);

Comment: While trying to investigate further, I came across an interesting finding for myself. I picked up one row which was being returned by the query on fts4 table and that row was not being returned by the like operator. that row contains text '(rain)' in it. Now normal like query is ignoring it as we are placing spaces before rain like this: '% rain %' so that a complete word would be returned. MATCH clause takes (rain) as rain. :)

Comment: I suggest you post these findings in your question as others will be see them when reading the question ;-)

Comment: I totally agree but how to do that? I am new to this stackoverflow. It does not even allow me to vote yet :D he he